# How to do annotation based RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am calling spring controller from ajax like `/test/new.ui`. How to do RequestMapping in controller method.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Raju

Comment: You read the documentation, you give it a try, you come back here if you can't make it work, and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping

Comment: Keith Donald wrote a good blog on how to use SpringMVC and ajax. http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

Answer (score 1):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test/") //This is optional to separate the /test/ part from the new.ui if you want to do other urls under the /test/
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping("new.ui")  //You can also do the entire url fragment here "/test/new.ui"
    public Object handleNewMethod(/* ModelAttributes, Errors, RequestParams here */) {
        // Code here
    }
}
```